# How can I set powershell's env in python

Tags: python, powershell

In `windows powershell terminal`. I can use `$Env:http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890";$Env:https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:7890"`.

But I now want execute a python shell in `windows powershell terminal` to do this. Can I do this? How to write the python script?

Comment: This may be tricky. I believe that environment variables are attached to each process. You set environment variables in python like ```os import; os.environ['SomeVar'] = 'value'``` but this doesn't persist into powershell. i.e. you can't then run ```$env:SomeVar``` in PowerShell and retrieve that variable. You may need to set a registry entry (assuming Windows) and retrieve it that way. What is the purpose of this? There may be a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, a *child* process - which a Python script invoked from a PowerShell session invariably is - cannot modify its *parent* process' environment.

Your only option is to:

- let the Python code output *instructions* for setting environment variables
- that the PowerShell session must then act on.

For instance:

```
# Call the Python script (simulated here with a simple command that prints a
# variable-name-value pair) and 
# split the output into variable name and value.
$name, $value = 
  (python -c 'print(''http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890'')') -split '=', 2

# Set the environment variable accordingly.
Set-Item "Env:$Name" $value

# Test:
$env:http_proxy # -> 'http://127.0.0.1:7890'
```